# Screenshot function works, but results in the Vulkan application attempting to recreate the swapchian and crashing

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I have been attempting to add the ability to create screenshots in my Vulkan application by closely following [Sascha Willems exmaple](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/screenshot/screenshot.cpp). At this point the function works exactly as intended, But after the function runs my program attempts to recreate the swapchain and returns the following output:

```
Image successfully saved! 
Present mode: Mailbox
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xaf5f3828 | vkCreateSwapchainKHR: value of pCreateInfo->preTransform contains flag bits that are not recognized members of VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR The Vulkan spec states: preTransform must be a valid VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xaf5f3828 | vkCreateSwapchainKHR: value of pCreateInfo->preTransform contains multiple members of VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR when only a single value is allowed The Vulkan spec states: preTransform must be a valid VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Performance Warning: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-SwapchainPreTransform ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba0ca580, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x214b6dd0 | vkCreateSwapchainKHR(): pCreateInfo->preTransform (Unhandled VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR) doesn't match the currentTransform (VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR) returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR, the presentation engine will transform the image content as part of the presentation operation.
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-minImageCount-01272 ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x7400c58b | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with minImageCount = -858993460, which is outside the bounds returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR() (i.e. minImageCount = 2, maxImageCount = 8). The Vulkan spec states: minImageCount must be less than or equal to the value returned in the maxImageCount member of the VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR structure returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR for the surface if the returned maxImageCount is not zero (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-minImageCount-01272)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-01279 ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x987713ee | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with a non-supported pCreateInfo->preTransform (i.e. Unhandled VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR).  Supported values are:
    VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR
. The Vulkan spec states: preTransform must be one of the bits present in the supportedTransforms member of the VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR structure returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR for the surface (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-preTransform-01279)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageExtent-01274 ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x7cd0911d | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with imageExtent = (3435973836,3435973836), which is outside the bounds returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(): currentExtent = (800,600), minImageExtent = (800,600), maxImageExtent = (800,600). The Vulkan spec states: imageExtent must be between minImageExtent and maxImageExtent, inclusive, where minImageExtent and maxImageExtent are members of the VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR structure returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR for the surface (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageExtent-01274)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageFormat-01778 ] Object 0: handle = 0x26dba352cf0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xc036022f | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with imageExtent = (-858993460,-858993460), which is bigger than max extent (32768,32768)returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties(): for imageFormat VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB with tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL The Vulkan spec states: The implied image creation parameters of the swapchain must be supported as reported by vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageFormat-01778)
failed to create swap chain!
```

So far, the only condition that recreates the swapchain is resizing my window (which makes sense). I have no clue what is triggering the call to recreate the swapchain. Right now the screenshot function calls after the frame is fully completed, but I also called it immediately after the frame content is rendered but there is no change in output. Here is the screenshot function:

```
    class ScreenshotTool {
        public:
            
            //assumes blitting is supported
            //Turns out that was a bad idea my 1060 does not in fact support blitting 
            //this is only for linear tiling, it is supprted for optimal tiling but i dont want to dive into something new right now
            //and no, I am not execty sure what it does (a boolean based combining or seperating function)
            
            void ScreenshotTool::takeScreenshot(VkImage srcImage, char* fileName, Device &device, Window window){
                bool supportsblit = false;
                //check for blit support later

                std::cout << "attempting to take screenshot \n";
                VkImageCreateInfo captureImageInfo{};
                VkExtent2D extent = window.getExtent();

                captureImageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
                captureImageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
                // Note that vkCmdBlitImage (if supported) will also do format conversions if the swapchain color format would differ
                captureImageInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
                captureImageInfo.extent.width = extent.width;
                captureImageInfo.extent.height = extent.height;
                captureImageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
                captureImageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
                captureImageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
                captureImageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
                captureImageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
                captureImageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
                captureImageInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;

                VkImage cptImage;

                std::cout << "creating image \n";
                vkCreateImage(device.device(), &captureImageInfo, nullptr, &cptImage);

                std::cout << "creating image memory \n";
                //create memory ???
                VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
                VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAllocInfo{};
                VkDeviceMemory cptImageMemory;
                vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device.device(), cptImage, &memRequirements);
                memAllocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
                memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;

                memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = device.findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);
                vkAllocateMemory(device.device(), &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &cptImageMemory);
                vkBindImageMemory(device.device(), cptImage, cptImageMemory, 0);

                std::cout << "chanigng image layouts \n";
                //changing image layouts 
                device.insertImageMemoryBarrier(
                cptImage,
                0,
                VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VkImageSubresourceRange{ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 });
                
                device.insertImageMemoryBarrier(
                srcImage,
                VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
                VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VkImageSubresourceRange{ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 });

                VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = device.beginSingleTimeCommands();
                //where blit becomes required, blit can do format conversions
                if(supportsblit){
                    VkOffset3D blitSize;
                    blitSize.x = extent.width;
                    blitSize.y = extent.height;
                    blitSize.z = 1;
                    VkImageBlit imageBlitRegion{};
                    imageBlitRegion.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                    imageBlitRegion.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                    imageBlitRegion.srcOffsets[1] = blitSize;
                    imageBlitRegion.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                    imageBlitRegion.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                    imageBlitRegion.dstOffsets[1] = blitSize;

                    vkCmdBlitImage(
                    commandBuffer,
                    srcImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                    cptImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                    1,
                    &imageBlitRegion,
                    VK_FILTER_NEAREST);
                }
                //will need to manually convert to rgb, eventually
                if(!supportsblit) {
                    VkImageCopy imageCopyRegion{};
                    imageCopyRegion.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                    imageCopyRegion.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                    imageCopyRegion.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                    imageCopyRegion.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                    imageCopyRegion.extent.width = extent.width;
                    imageCopyRegion.extent.height = extent.height;
                    imageCopyRegion.extent.depth = 1;

                    // Issue the copy command
                    vkCmdCopyImage(
                        commandBuffer,
                        srcImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                        cptImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                        1,
                        &imageCopyRegion);
                }

                device.endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);

                //change image format again to write to file
                device.insertImageMemoryBarrier(
                cptImage,
                VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VkImageSubresourceRange{ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 });

                device.insertImageMemoryBarrier(
                srcImage,
                VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT,
                VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                VkImageSubresourceRange{ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 });


                std::cout << "extracting image data \n";
                //get image layout
                VkImageSubresource subResource { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0 };
                VkSubresourceLayout subResourceLayout;
                vkGetImageSubresourceLayout(device.device(), cptImage, &subResource, &subResourceLayout);

                const char* data;
                vkMapMemory(device.device(), cptImageMemory, 0, VK_WHOLE_SIZE, 0, (void**)&data);
                //data += subResourceLayout.offset;

                //using stb to save as jpg not ppm because I can

                std::cout << "writing to jpg \n";
                if(stbi_write_jpg(fileName, extent.width, extent.height, 4, (void*)data, 100) == 0) {
                    std::cout << "bad doo doo \n";
                }
                std::cout << "Image successfully saved! \n";

                vkUnmapMemory(device.device(), cptImageMemory);
                vkFreeMemory(device.device(), cptImageMemory, nullptr);
                vkDestroyImage(device.device(), cptImage, nullptr);
            }
```

Everything else is in my [repo](https://github.com/SrMeissel/Vulkan-game-engine)

Comment: I've been doing more digging, and it seems the results of 'vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR' change which seems impossible. It seems this way because 'VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT' is not a supported usage flag only after taking the screenshot. I am very confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, and it had nothing to do with Vulkan. I was passing my window object which is a unique pointer. I should have passed a pointer or simply passed the extent, which is what I ended up doing. it works!